# passing query string from asp to htm file vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have 2 files one SendEmail.asp and One Home.htm file.

In Home.htm I am passing some values in VB script to SendEmail by:

```
document.formname.action = "SendEmail.asp?homepage =" + window.location.href;
```

Now when email is done successfully I want to send parameter to htm file and show message of success.

Right now I am redirecting to home.htm in this way:

```
response.redirect(request.QueryString("homepage"))
```

If I add any query string like `home.htm?n1=success` then I am getting error. Please give your valuable suggestions and answers.

Code In home.htm File:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function fnSubmit()
{
  var retValue=true;
  if(retValue)
  {
    if(document.formname.txtName.value=='')
    {
        alert("Please enter Name");
        document.formname.txtName.focus();
        retValue=false;
    }
  }
  if(retValue)
  {
    if(checkEmail(document.formname.txtEmail, "Email", false)==false)
    {
        alert("Please enter Email");
        document.formname.txtEmail.focus();
        retValue=false;
    }
  }
  if(retValue)
  {
    if(document.formname.txtPhone.value=='')
    {
        alert("Please enter Phone No.");
        document.formname.txtPhone.focus();
        retValue=false;
    }
  }
  if(retValue)
  {
    if(document.formname.txtQuery.value=='')
    {
        alert("Please enter Your Query");
        document.formname.txtQuery.focus();
        retValue=false;
    }
  }
  if(retValue)
  {      
      document.formname.action = "SendEmail.asp?homepage =" + window.location.href;
      document.formname.submit(); 
  }
return false;

</script>
```

on Button Click:

```
onclick="javascript:fnSubmit();"
```

In SendEmail.asp file:

```
<%@  language="VBScript" %>
<%Option Explicit%>
<%
Dim Uploader, File, FileSys, FilePath, UploadFileName, strHTML, subject, Mailer, EmailAddress
subject = request("txtSubject")
EmailAddress = request("txtEmail")
strHTML = " Name : "&request("txtName")&" Email : "&request("txtEmail")&" Query : "&request("txtQuery")

Set Mailer=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        Mailer.Subject="accurate-data-entry.com:: new"&subject
        Mailer.From= request("txtEmail")                
        Mailer.To="abc@gmail.com "
        Mailer.HTMLBody=strHTML        
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
       ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.gmail.com"
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=465  
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="abc@gmail.com" 
Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item _ 
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="xyz"  
        Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Update
        Mailer.send
        Set Mailer = nothing   
'Response.write("Done Successful") 
response.redirect(request.QueryString("homepage "))
%>
```

If I am adding Response.Write I am getting error message:

> CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
>
> The transport failed to connect to the server.
>
> /SendEmail.asp, line 41

The line 41 is Mailer.send

Thanks

Comment: what is the error type. Post  codes along with your javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit your form with AJAx using jquery.  Jquery will take all your form variables and submit them to your asp page to send the email.  In the asp page, get rid of the response.redirect.  The redirect is not necessary and will break the ajax response.   Instead in the asp page do a response.write "THANKS FOR YOUR MESSAGE " or something like that.

Take a look at the Jquery Ajax docs.

```
    $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "SendEmail.asp",
   dataType: 'text',
   data: { username: username, password: password },
   success: function(data) {
     if(data == 'Incorrect password'){
       $('#results_callback').html(data);        
     }
     else{
       $('#results').html(data);
     }
   },
   error: function(msg) {
    alert("O NOES");
   }
});
```

Comment: I also want to  upload a File and attach with mail. I tried ajax it worked fine but when I attached a FileUploader again error started

Comment: take a look at this github plugin
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Classic-ASP

Comment: And someting like this as the asp script to handle the upload. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/upload-images-in-classic-asp/5031731.

Or you can use aspupload.com component